# Parallelization of a primality test (python)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I coded a primality test and it works. It's called the bosma-test and it checks whether numbers of the form h * 2^k+1 are prime, where h is odd and h<2^k.
Here is a short outline of the functionality:
Let n = h * 2^k + 1.
The test takes a list of finite prime numbers.
It then chooses a prime number D and checks whether the jacobi-symbol J(n, D) is 0 or -1. If it is 0, the number n is not prime. So it returns False.
If the symbol is -1, it calculates the congruence D^( (n-1) / 2) mod n. If it's congruent to -1, the number is prime and it returns True. Otherwise it is not and it returns False.
In case that the symbol is +1, we just use another prime (the primes are checked in ascending order).
If and only if every symbol is +1, the test returns "-1" which lets me know, that the list is too short. But this not important here).

I coded it and it works, here is my code:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pickle
from sympy.ntheory import jacobi_symbol

PRIMES_FILE = Path("/primes_up_to_10_7")

with open(PRIMES_FILE, 'rb') as file:
    primes = pickle.load(file)
primes.remove(2)

def bosma(h, k, primes):
    for D in primes:
        jacobi = jacobi_symbol( h*2**k + 1, D)
        if jacobi == 0:
            return False
        if jacobi == -1:
            exp = h*2**(k-1)
            n = 2*exp+1
            return True if pow(D, exp, n) == n-1 else False
    return -1

coeff_lower = 1
coeff_upper = 100
exponent = 20000

def main():
    print("Script started")
    for coefficient in range(coeff_lower, coeff_upper+1):
        print(f"{coefficient} * 2^{exponent}+1: ", bosma(coefficient, exponent, primes))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now comes my question.
I want to run this code on our cluster in university. Therefore, I want to parallelize it. That means, I choose an exponent and a lower and an upper bound for the coefficients.
Let's say, the exponent is 50.000 and the bounds are 10.000 and 20.000.
Then I want that one kernel (is that the right word) calculates 10.001 * 2^50.000 + 1 with the bosma test, the next one 10.003 * 2^50.000 + 1 and so on.
Since the calculations take different time, a kernel shall always take the next "free" coefficient and do the bosmatest with this coefficient and the fixed exponent 50.000.

But I don't know how I could do that.

So I know that I can get the amouont of kernels via multiprocessing.cpu_count()

But how do I go on?
P.S: I can upload and attach the primes-file if you like.

Comment: You should read up on either the `multiprocessing` package or the `concurrent.futures` package. Then you should make a first attempt at a multiprocessing solution and if you encounter difficulties, only then post a question.

Comment: See [this demo](https://ideone.com/nVXSbS), from which you might be able get a jump start. This is meant to be read along with the Python 3 documentation.